# Plone Flowplayer FLV files

Tags: plone, flv, converters, flowplayer, avi

I have a client with a site built on plone and he wanted some avi videos playable from the site.

Flowplayer is installed and I converted the 33! videos from avi to flv for flowplayer to play

When i go to play the videos with the flowplayer it just plays the audio, but the strange this is if you rewind and start the video again it then plays properly.

Any help or advice how to solve this problem would be gratefully recieved

Comment: This issue is not probably related, but is an encoding issue with videos. You did not mention how you converted videos. Try with known good working video files like Sintel MP4 trailer: http://www.sintel.org/download

Comment: It's only Plone issue if you can confirm that videos work fine from local disk (file://) or other protocol and do not work with Plone

Answer (score 1):

I just enabled flowplayer on a Plone 4 site, and the video played fine.  I agree with earlier post that's it's most likely an encoding issue with your flv.  For info, I used ffmpeg to convert .mp4 /avc file to .flv, and that worked fine on our site.